# Who is the first woman to play USCF rated chess in all 50 US states?

Tags: statistics, uscf

On X/Twitter [this tweet](https://twitter.com/gauss1181/status/1713434001778835618) appeared by somebody called Megan:

> Today was a historic day for my #chess life. I wrapped up the 50 states quest in Alaska, with Fairbanks Chess Club's #NationalChessDay  G/15 d5 rapid event today. I scored 4.0/6, and became the 1st woman to play USCF rated chess in all 50 US states!
>
> Thanks #chesspunks for believing in and cheering on me along the years of this journey!

From the replies it looks like this was widely known about. They include from people like Susan Polgar and Carsten Hansen.

Does anyone have more information about this, like who is Megan?

Comment: Her other tweets have a bit more detail about her.  [Example](https://twitter.com/gauss1181/status/1631451443520585728/photo/1) If you search for her name + chess you can find additional details (such as [this link](https://www.il-chess.org/meet-our-members/1304-ica-meet-our-members-megan-chen) )

Comment: It might be me, but I fail to see the achievement: when I finished the epic task of playing chess sitting on every one of the ~100 chairs in our chess club I haven't written a tweet about it.